# Nearby goes in sleep mode in background after few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, google-nearby

It seems that when our app goes in background (user click on "Home") on iOS the nearby service ends to work (messageLostHandler and/or messageFoundHandler are not fired until the app is opened by the user).

Is that an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't behave that way if you've set it up to work in the background.

Double-check the list of requirements on [this page](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/pub-sub#background_operation).  And take a look at the [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-nearby/tree/master/NearbyBackgroundExample), which publishes and subscribes in the background.  If your app scans for beacons (vs. nearby phone/tablets), take a look at this [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-nearby/tree/master/NearbyBeacons) instead.

Comment: we have the same behavior with your app as well

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  I can't get our sample app to NOT work in the background, even when I decline all of the permissions it bombards me with on startup the first time.

A couple of things to try:
- Have you tried it on another device?
- Can you send me the console logs from the app when it goes into the background, and then back into the foreground a few seconds later?  Maybe that will give me a hint of what's going wrong.

And sorry for the hassle!  Once we nail down the cause, I'll probably add to the existing documentation of scenarios like this to watch out for.